# Is it possible to restrict the aad registered application to use only one Sharepoint site

Tags: c#, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have an Application registered in Azure active directory, i am using c# and 'Microsoft graph' to get all my documents and other stuff from the sharepoint sites.

Now, since i wanted to use only one team site to get all my needs, i wanted to know if there is any way to restrict use of only one team site in one aad application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a user vote about this issue: [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/37796059-restrict-permissions-to-app-only-azure-ad-applicat). Microsoft claims to be working on it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it can not be implemented in azure ad microsoft graph. All of the permissions are for "**all site collections**". So if you want to implement this requirement, you can just do it by code.
[image]